# Can't validate null string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have the following code:

```
NSString *content = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"mykey"];
NSLog(@"string is %@",content);
if ([content stringIsEmpty]){
   NSLog(@"empty string");
}else{
  NSLog(@"string is not empty");
}
```

stringIsEmpty is class category on `NSString`:

```
- (BOOL ) stringIsEmpty {
    if ((NSNull *) self == [NSNull null]) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (self == nil) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([self length] == 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The output is:

```
string is (null)
string is not empty
```

How could it be null and not empty at the same time?

Comment: Note that `-[NSUserDefaults stringForKey]` either returns a `NSString`  or `nil`, but never a `NSNull` object. Therefore a test `[content length] > 0` would be sufficient.

Comment: but that doesn't work. As you see my method returns NO

Comment: That has been explained in the answers below. If `content == nil` then `[content stringIsEmpty:YES]` returns `NO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that:

`[content stringIsEmpty:YES]`

will return false (`NO`), when `content` is `nil`. So your code will take the

```
 NSLog(@"string is not empty");
```

branch. This would be better:

```
if (content && [content stringIsEmpty:YES]){
    ...
```

A better way of doing this would be reversing the semantics of the method:

```
if ([content stringIsNotEmpty]) {
```

this would work finely because when `content` is `nil` it would return `NO`, when it is not `nil`, it would execute your method.

EDIT:

In Objective-C, sending a message to `nil` is legal and by definition will evaluate to `nil`. Google for "objective c sending message to nil".

In another language (C++), your code would crash (actually undefined behaviour, but to make things simple).

Comment: But I have a check: if (self == nil)

Comment: just a question: if you send a message to a `nil` object, what do you think will happen? for sure your code will not be executed...

Comment: Actually, you `(NSNull *) self == [NSNull null]` won't ever happen. If the object is an instance of `NSNull` a method on `NSString` won't be called and you will get a `missing selector`.

Comment: @Odelya: see also my edited answer for more detail about sending a message to `nil`.

Comment: I added to the category:  if (!self){
        return YES;
    }
 but still it won't help

Comment: @Odelya: If `content == nil` then `[content stringIsEmpty]` *does not call your method at all*.

Comment: I actually added if content==nil or my method

Comment: But how can I check the nil in class category?

Answer (score 1):

I use a small function to test for emptiness. It works on more than just strings:

```
static inline BOOL isEmpty(id thing) {
    return thing == nil
        || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
        && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
        || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
        && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
}
```

I usually import it in my pch file - you can see it along with attribution: https://gist.github.com/325926

As @sergio has already pointed out - when your string is `nil` you can't send it messages that test it for nil-ness - as sending messages to nil will do nothing for void methods, and return nil where the method returns something.

**also**

you are calling your method with a parameter

```
if ([content stringIsEmpty:YES])
```

but your method declaration doesn't take one:

```
- (BOOL ) stringIsEmpty {
```

What's that all about?

Comment: I change the class category like this: - (BOOL ) stringIsEmpty {
    
   return self == nil
    || ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
        && [(NSData *)self length] == 0)
    || ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
        && [(NSArray *)self count] == 0);} but it wouldn't work

Comment: That' isn't going to work, because if the string is `nil` the method returns `nil`, but you want it to return YES. It's pointless adding a category to a class to test for nil, because any such method is going to return nil.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the 'content == nil' case outside of the method.

If you want to be able to call just one method, change the method to something that tests for a positive, such as "stringHasContent", returning `YES` if `self.length > 0`.